# Where i need to position fill application form in swimlane !

Tags: uml, use-case, activity-diagram

I am writting a sequence diagram where custome fill a application from for a bank

here i have two swim lane ..one is customer and another is bank

in which position i need to position "fill application form"  activity?

Should it be in customer swim lane or in bank swim lane

since the customer is filling application so shouldn't it be for customer swim lane?

but customer is filling banks application form so shouldn't it be for bank swim lane?

Answer (score 1):

You are confused.

> There is no swimlane in sequence
>   diagram. Swimlanes are in Activity
>   diagram.

If you try to model a business process using sequence diagram this is wrong. Sequence diagrams are for exploring real software objects interactions.

[image]
[image]